# How to get rid of a broken SPField? Field is not updatable / deletable

Tags: spfield

I have a broken field in my site collection that is not updatable / deletable.
Every change that I try to make on the field does nothing - the field is in the same state as before. I tried it via UI, code and SharePoint Manager.

Is there any way to get rid of it? Is accessing the SharePoint Content Database directly the only way?

Comment: Never touch the Databases directly! If you do so your installation will go into an unsupported state and you won't receive any support from MS.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried powershell?

I did a quick Google search and found the below articles, it might prove useful:

http://www.sharepointfix.com/2011/04/powershell-script-to-delete-site.html 
http://ryandunn.co/sharepoint-deleting-a-column-from-a-list-using-powershell